# Can I travel to the UK with an Afghan handwritten passport?

Tags: visas, uk, passports, spouses, afghan-citizens

I have an Afghan handwritten passport. Does the UK issue visas on Afghan handwritten passports? I can't get an electronic passport because I live in Peshawar, Pakistan and the Afghan consulate only issues handwritten passport. My passport is valid until August 2019.

Comment: Questions about long-term visas, like a spouse visa, should go to http://expatriates.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: No, handwritten Afghan passports are no longer valid, as of the end of 2017, according to [Afghanistan's Ministry of Foreign Affairs](https://www.econsulate.gov.af/en/passport.html)

Answer (score 4):

As [Giorgio](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/30343/giorgio) commented:

"No, handwritten Afghan passports are no longer valid, as of the end of 2017, according to [Afghanistan's Ministry of Foreign Affairs](https://www.econsulate.gov.af/en/passport.html)"

> The Ministry of Foreign Affairs of Afghanistan (MoFA) began issuing the new machine-readable (computerized) Diplomatic and Service Passports in 2011 (1390), and thereafter in September 2012 (1391), started the issuance of Ordinary Passport. In 2012, MoFA started to issue passports through six zones around the world with the exception of Iran and Pakistan and successfully completed this process by the end of 2015. Therefore, after the end of 2017, the handwritten Afghan Passports are no longer deemed valid.